# .NET Framework 2.0 and 4.0 Visual Studio Toolbox item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, custom-controls

I want to install two different version of my WinForms custom control in the Visual Studio Toolbox: the .NET Framework 2.0 version and the .NET Framework 4.0 one. I found this professional solution http://vstudiotoolbox.codeplex.com/ but selecting the proper .NET Framework is not covered.

Where can I learn more?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lextm.com/2012/08/how-to-install-custom-controls-to-visual-studio-part-i/

This covers what is required to install a .NET 2 control. If you want to install .NET 4's, you can follow

http://www.lextm.com/2012/08/how-to-install-custom-controls-to-visual-studio-part-ii/

My open source project is a sample for you to review how to perform the needed steps,

https://github.com/lextm/actionlistwinforms

Inno Setup is used to author the installer, but the tricks should apply to other installer techniques.

Comment: I cannot find your ToolboxManager source code it the referenced repository, can you show me where it is?

Comment: I lost that as my old laptop crashed. Why not decompile it using ILSpy or another similar tool?

Comment: I decompiled it and it's very similar to original project, therefore it fails as the original one.

Comment: when you said "it failed", I am confused. It is your responsibility to register .NET 2 and .NET 4 assemblies to corresponding GAC locations (as I stated in the blog posts). After that you only need to create a single Toolbox tab (and items) for a single .NET version (such as .NET 2). If you check out https://github.com/lextm/ActionListWinForms/blob/master/setup.iss, you will see that toolbox.exe is only called to install the .NET 2 assembly to VS. VS is smart enough to switch the toolbox tab/items silently to the .NET 4 assembly in GAC when you open a .NET 4 project.